# Probabilities of all classifications in knn in R

Tags: r, knn

When using the knn() function in package class in R, there is an argument called "prob". If I make this true, I get the probability of that particular value being classified to whatever it is classified as.
I have a dataset where the classifier has 9 levels. Is there any way in which I can get the probability of a particular observation for all the 9 levels?

Comment: Please consider changing the answer. Most important `knnflex` is removed from CRAN.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This question still require proper answer.

If the probability for the most probable class is needed then the `class` package will be still suited. The clue is to set the argument `prob` to TRUE and `k` to higher than default 1 - `class::knn(tran, test, cl, k = 5, prob = TRUE)`. The `k` has to be higher than default 1 to not get always 100%  probability for each observation.

However if you want to get probabilities for each of the classes I will recommend the `caret::knn3` function with `predict` one.

```r
data(iris3)
train <- rbind(iris3[1:25,,1], iris3[1:25,,2], iris3[1:25,,3])
test <- rbind(iris3[26:50,,1], iris3[26:50,,2], iris3[26:50,,3])
cl <- factor(c(rep("s",25), rep("c",25), rep("v",25)))

# class package
# take into account k higher than 1 and prob equal TRUE
model <- class::knn(train, test, cl, k = 5, prob = TRUE)
tail(attributes(model)$prob, 10)
#>  [1] 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 0.8 1.0 1.0 0.8

# caret package
model2 <- predict(caret::knn3(train, cl, k = 3), test)
tail(model2, 10)
#>               c s         v
#> [66,] 0.0000000 0 1.0000000
#> [67,] 0.0000000 0 1.0000000
#> [68,] 0.0000000 0 1.0000000
#> [69,] 0.0000000 0 1.0000000
#> [70,] 0.0000000 0 1.0000000
#> [71,] 0.0000000 0 1.0000000
#> [72,] 0.3333333 0 0.6666667
#> [73,] 0.0000000 0 1.0000000
#> [74,] 0.0000000 0 1.0000000
#> [75,] 0.3333333 0 0.6666667
```

<sup>Created on 2021-07-20 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know the `knn()` function in `class` only returns the highest probability.

However, you can use the `knnflex` package which allows you to return all probability levels using `knn.probability` (see [here](http://www.cs.upc.edu/~belanche/Docencia/mineria/Practiques/R/knnflex.pdf), page 9-10).

Comment: Thanks Maximilian. This is exactly what I needed :)

Answer (score 2):

I know there is an answer already marked here, but this is possible to complete without utilizing another function or package.

What you can do instead is build your knn model `knn_model` and check out it's attributes for the "prob" output, as such.

`attributes(knn_model)$prob`